# Exclude tag changes from 'active' list

Tags: feature-request, editing, views, sorting, recent-activity

Especially on the smaller stackexchange sites, the main page's active list is the main place to go to see the new activity. However sometimes, new answers and questions are lost, or flushed through too quickly by much retagging of old questions. I'm all for retagging old questions as it helps keep the site organized, but it would be nice if I could view activity *excluding* those posts that have no meaningful content change. I know that just changing the tags doesn't count as an edit (say, for the [Strunk and White badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white)) so maybe we can have a way of viewing recently edited posts in addition to recently active posts.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46729.

Answer (score 5):

There's currently no way to retag without bumping, and sometimes such retagging is necessary.

Often, though, what you want to accomplish by retagging can be done (and much more easily!) by a ♦ moderator by merging tags, which does not bump the questions as active. If you ever find yourself wanting to retag a bunch of questions the same way, consider asking a mod in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468) whether it can be done by merging instead, or [propose it as a question here on meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

When retagging really is necessary, I won't agree merely-retagged posts shouldn't appear as active: sometimes such retaggings need to be checked for accuracy. Perhaps, though, retaggings by a high-rep user should not bump questions?

Note also that in any specific case of mass-retagging, you can (temporarily if you like) set the questions' new tag as "ignored" (on [the homepage](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), on the right), which will grey them out on the active-questions list.

Comment: I agree they should be 'active'. I'm just suggesting we have a view called 'active' and a view called 'edited'. People can use whatever they want. I've tried to clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think older questions that do not have an accepted answer should be bumped with any activity. This gives fresh eyes a chance to review and possibly answer the question.

Comment: Acceptance is not key. An asker can accept a bad answer, or not accept any answer even though there's a great one. A better measure of whether a question need more views IMO is how many upvotes it has on its answers. (The software already bumps questions with no net upvoted answers (or, at least, I think that's the measure used), even without activity, incidentally.)

Comment: @msh210: point taken. But whatever metrics used to determine whether the question need be bumped, it is still very useful. When I edited a typo on this answer, bumping it to the top of the list, I got another good answer (although not what I'm looking for) within half an hour: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12001/603 . What I was trying to say in my answer is that questions that are still looking for answers benefit from being bumped. If, when retagging a bunch of questions, only those that need it get bumped, it would be useful without flooding the front page

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Older questions should be bumped for fresh attention (as already happens to a limited extent), but with a large-scale retagging, they shouldn't all be bumped *at once*.